# Wordpress Site not Load in IE (Firefox & Chrome are ok)

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

i have 2 websites that i build with WordPress , both of them works well in Firefox and chrome without any problems .

but i found that both my WordPress site wont load in Internet explore at all

this error show when i try to reach :

This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address https://owjgraphic.com/ is correct.

•Look for the page with your search engine.

•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

that's very weird ! i contact to my host administrator and they say it`s not related to us and you must found the problem by yourself

Comment: Is "https://owjgraphic.com/" your website built with WordPress? I test it in IE 11 and it can display well in IE 11. The result is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGj3h.png. Could you please inform us which version of IE are you using? Can other websites work well in your IE browser? Besides, you could open F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

I use IE to load without showing the above problems.

First, you could use the F12 developer tool to check if there’s error.

Second, you could refer to the following links:

1. [Website theme and software version.](https://www.infyways.com/how-to-fix-wordpress-and-ie-compatibility-issues/)
2. Check IE compatibility mark ["x-ua-compatible".](https://frankcode.net/2013/10/17/a-guide-to-ie-compatibility-view-and-x-ua-compatible/)

In addition, if you still can't make it work on IE, hopefully you could provide information about the code or settings that is related to browser loading to reproduce your problem.